# 10 Teams, 2 Divisions Secheduling Question

Tags: real-analysis

You have 10 teams, divided into 2 'Pools' or 'Divisions.

- Each team must play each of the 4 other teams in THEIR division 3 times (12 matches).
- Each team must play each of the 5 other teams in the OPPOSITE division 2 times (10 matches)

The season goes for 22 Weeks, there needs to be 5 matches a week:

e.g. 
Week 1:
1 vs 2
3 vs 4
5 vs A
B vs C
D vs E

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: sorry yes.
 
I need help creating the schedule to adhere to the criteria listed